# import numpy giving ImportError: DLL load failed: %1 is not a valid Win32 application

Tags: python-2.7, numpy, importerror, ptvs

I am using python tools for visual studio express 2013. I am not able to import numpy in it. Could successfully import other modules like re and math

import numpy gives following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "`<stdin>`", line 1, in `<module>`

 File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\numpy\__init__.py", line 153, in <module>
from . import add_newdocs
 File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\numpy\add_newdocs.py", line 13, in <module>
from numpy.lib import add_newdoc
 File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
from .type_check import *
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\type_check.py", line 11, in <module>
import numpy.core.numeric as _nx
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\__init__.py", line 6, in <module>
from . import multiarray
ImportError: DLL load failed: %1 is not a valid Win32 application.
```

How can this be resolved?

Comment: How did you install numpy? (It sounds like you might have gotten 64-bit numpy on top of a 32-bit Python install, or vice versa)

Comment: @PavelMinaev Thanks!! U were right. I had both python 2.7.8 and pythonxy(2.7.6) installed. Uninstalled pythonxy and the problem is resolved!

Comment: How did you find out you had both versions installed?